# Is the source code for OS X kernel logging messages available via XNU, or is it "proprietary."

Tags: macos, kernel

It would be kind of nice to understand just exactly WHAT all those messages that appear in log files really mean. I'm not necessarily talking about errors, but even informational messages. I realize that a lot of applications post messages in log files, and I don't expect to be able to find the source available for them, but it would be nice if I could find out exactly what those generated by the kernel and other low level applications, like launchd really mean.

Does anyone know if this is in the XNU source code anywhere, or is this all part of the "proprietary" part of the OS X kernel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the open source part of OS X, [Darwin](http://www.puredarwin.org/downloads).  I suppose you could look through that, however maybe someone who knows the answer could be more direct.